# when logout Why i have to wait 5 second to redirect to homepage?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, redirect, security, logout

Would someone explain me for this feature please ?
I do ask GPT , it say "It is designed to prevent potential security vulnerabilities, such as session fixation attacks."
"This delay ensures that the session is fully cleared and invalidated before allowing a new session to be created"
But it not clear to me enough . 
1.how I can evaluate 5 second is enough, If I reduce it how I can check it satisfy above ? 
2.Is it have a better way than wait ?

Comment: Iam not aware of reasosn but what we generally do is to redirect directlly to home page without any wait, jsut click on logout and redirect to home page to give user better experience. You can assure cookies regarding login is destroyed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to the homepage after logout, wait 5 second define in `logout-redirect.js` file
and message in `logout.phtml` file, You can change accordingly.

> Path :
> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/logout-redirect.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (data) {
        $($.mage.redirect(data.url, 'assign', 5000));
    };
});
```

> Path :
> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml

```
<p><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You have signed out and will go to our homepage in 5 seconds.')) ?></p>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Customer/js/logout-redirect": {
                "url": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl())) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this js file into your custom theme

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/logout-redirect.js

If you want to extend the time of redirection after the logout just change the **5000** value according your requirement save the code and run commands, here **1000 = 1 second** so **5000 = 5 seconds**

If you want to redirect immediately to home page after the logout then just remove **5000** from the code save the code and run commands.

In order to change the message, override this phtml file into your custom theme and make your changes

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml

Comment: no, i want to know why it's 5s ?

Comment: I guess it is just a functionality of magento, I think for the better e-commerce experience to customer/user magento redirect them to home page just so they can buy/purchase or check the items/products. I think it's just a marketing strategy